# Can the 'show total up and down votes' be added to all Stack Exchange sites with 1000 rep to any site?

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface

Having more than 1000 reputation points on Stack Overflow, I always am interested in seeing whether content with a lot of votes was at all controversial or has only up votes, like so:

[image]

However, when I move to other Stack Exchange sites that I enjoy reading, but do not have sufficient reputation points to do this, I find myself deeply missing it. I can understand it's more of a feature frequent users will use, but may confuse new users. But is there anyway this could get enabled for all Stack Exchange sites if you have 1000 reputation points on any of them?

Comment: No freebies! Earn the privilege! :)

Comment: @Bart - So you want us to abolish the association bonus?

Comment: @Oded So you actually listen to what I say? I've got to use that at some point...

Comment: @Bart - I _hear_ what you say. Listen? Sometimes ;)

Comment: Or go find that script that lets you do it on all sites.

Comment: @Doorknob [This one?](http://stackapps.com/questions/3082/view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep)

Comment: @Clive Yes, I was too lazy to find it :P

Comment: I don't care about other exchange sites, but couldn't we do it so if we have the privilege on SO, then we can have it here on meta?

Comment: Here:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/view-vote-totals-without/oibfliilcglieepgkdkahpfiiigdijdd if on chrome.

Comment: @Oded I certainly want to abolish the association bonus in favour of making some privileges depend on the network reputation.

Answer (score 8):

I have an issue with your claim:

> but may confuse new users

How? If they are new, they will *certainly* not be exposed to this feature anywhere. They can only miss it if they have been exposed to it and only exposed to it if they are not new.

As for enabling it everywhere if you have over 1000 rep in one SE - I would say you need to be active in a site before you gain more privileges (above those gained for association bonus).

Comment: I assumed it had a rep requirement only because new users will not understand the system enough to utilize it and therefore it may only confuse them.  I disagree that this really qualifies as a 'privilege', since it only allows the user to get information but not actually affect the site in any way like say commenting, voting, and moderation does.

Comment: @KDiTraglia - One of the issues here is that of performance. It is _expensive_ for us to get the two bits of information, much more so than just the score (which is denormalized).

Comment: `They can only miss it if they have been exposed to it and only exposed to it if they are not new.` - Couldn't agree more, I hate going to a SE site where I don't have enough rep and not being able to see the up/down votes

Comment: @psubsee2003 Even worse is not being able to insta-edit.

Comment: @Oded why not denormalize those two bits of information as well? It won't be expensive memory-wise (it's just two extra ints per post) or speed-wise (either you update one value, or two values in the same row)

Comment: @JanDvorak - Not disagreeing with you, but doing so will take some effort and time and may require us to go offline (for populating the data), for little gain. I am not the expert on the technical specifics, however...

Comment: Concerning going offline - Google BigTable is able to generate new indexes on the fly: First, the index is and marked as being deployed. Any writes write to this index, even if it's not yet populated with the old data. Then, a job is launched to traverse existing entries and add them to the index. When the job finishes, it marks the index as being ready for use. This allows the queries to read from it. A similar process can be used when adding a new column to a relational database: update schema, update writers, run an asynchronous job to fill existing data, update readers, set column not null

Comment: @JanDvorak - We are not using Google BigTable, but SQL Server. I know it also has online indexing options, but as I mentioned, I am not the team expert on the subject...

Comment: It's annoying to gain 1000 on 100 sites just to get access to the most basic features, especially since earning rep on small sites is much harder than on SO.